# AS3 | issue with removeListener

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
function startDrawMarker():void {
    if (isStartDrawMarker!=false) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    } else {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    }
}
```

When 'isStartDrawMarker' = true, as3 add Event Listener, but when 'isStartDrawMarker' = false, as3 isn't remove Listener.

Comment: I'm guessing we are going to need more information to help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: with this implementation you have to :
- change value of isStartDrawMarker 
- call startDrawMarker method to remove/add the listener
if you want to do i in a single move I have added a long answer below

another solution is to remove onDownMarker the listener on the MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP event ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to listen for `MOUSE_DOWN` only when `isStartDrawMarker` is true, it will be:

```
function startDrawMarker():void {
    if (isStartDrawMarker) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    } else {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds, are, that when you call "startDrawMarker" and isStartDrawMarker is false, the references are not the same as when you call it and it is true.  If the listener is not being removed with the code as provided, and everything else is correct, then you may want to try to use a weak listener.  Also you can make your code easier to read, by checking if "isStartDrawmarker" is true, rather than "!= false"

```
function startDrawMarker():void {
    if (isStartDrawMarker) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker, false, 0, true);
    } else {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, changing the value of isStartDrawMarker will not call startDrawMarker method, that's why ^^

With AS3 you can create get/set when you want to add behaviour on variable change.
To do so rename you class variable

```
public var isStartDrawMarker
```

in

```
private var _isStartDrawMarker
```

And use get/set like below

```
/**
* get the current value
*/
public function get isStartDrawMarker():Boolean
{
return _isStartDrawMarker;
}

/**
* change the current value AND automatically add/remove a mousedown listener on the stage
*/
public function set isStartDrawMarker(value:Boolean):void
{
    _isStartDrawMarker = value;
    if (_isStartDrawMarker == true) {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    } else {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownMarker);
    }
}
```

Here is how to use it in your code (note you always use isStartDrawMarker not _isStartDrawMarker witch is private)

```
this.isStartDrawMarker = true; // will set to true AND add the listener
this.isStartDrawMarker = false; // will set to false AND remove the listener
```

or

```
myClass.isStartDrawMarker = true; // will set to true AND add the listener
myClass.isStartDrawMarker = false; // will set to false AND remove the listener
```